# Measures=distributions, what is wrong?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, distribution-theory

We know that in $\mathbb{R}^N$ distributions can be defined as $D(\mathbb{R}^N)=C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)'$ and Radon finites measures as $m(\mathbb{R}^N)=C_0(\mathbb{R}^N)'$. So, from this definitions we obtain that $D(\mathbb{R}^N) \subset m(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

On the other hand, if $\mu\in m(\mathbb{R}^N)$, the operator $R_\mu (\varphi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi d\mu$, with $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$, belongs to $D(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Thus, we can identify $m(\mathbb{R}^N) \subset D(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

It is clear that there is something which is wrong in this reasoning, but I don't know where it fails.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning in the first paragraph. Why do you think that $D \subset m$?

Answer (score 4):

Your first paragraph falsely suggests a containment going in the wrong direction. (Also, using $D$ for distributions is considerably contrary to convention, where some version of "D" would be used for test functions...) Yes, we do have test functions naturally injecting to continuous compact-support functions: $C^\infty_c\to C^o_c$. Taking duals reverses the natural injection:
$$
\hbox{finite Radon measures} \;=\; (C^o_c)^* \;\longrightarrow\; (C^\infty_c)^* \;=\; \hbox{distributions}
$$
Not the other direction.

Note: as @s.harp kindly noted, my previous "inclusion" instead of "natural injection" could too easily give an incorrect impression about whether in $A\subset B$ the topology on $A$ is the subset topology from $B$. In the present case, this is certainly not the case! :)

EDIT: another technical point is that to know that the duals inject uses the density of $C^\infty_c$ in $C^o_o$. When we ask about the density of (finite, Radon...) measures in distributions, we need to specify a topology. If we take the weak dual topology, then in fact (going back to ideas from Garding and others 60+ years ago) test functions are dense in nearly anything with a reasonable topology... although this has some technicalities. So, yes, for *specific* (not so abstract...) reasons measures are weak-dual dense in distributions, because, in fact, test functions themselves are already weak-dual dense in distributions.

I guess a bit more can be said about these things... :)

Comment: Perhaps instead of "inclusion" it is more appropriate to say "natural injection", because the topology of $(C_c)^*$ is not the same as the restriction of the topology of $C_0$.

Comment: @s.harp, indeed, ... thanks!

Comment: I don't see the poitn where you say that $C_c^\infty\to C_c \implies  (C_c)^*\to (C_c^\infty)^*$. That is, for example $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2)^*\to (\mathbb{R}^3)^*$

Comment: Indeed, more can be said. We have more than density of test functions in the weak dual, namely, test functions are sequentially dense in the space of distributions with the strong topology. Also these types of situations has been formalized through the notions of "space of distributions" and "normal spaces of distributions". Finally, regarding weak versus strong topology, the following post may be useful https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362509/strong-topology-on-a-topological-vector-space/362536#362536